# In mongoDB query with lumen : $or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, lumen

In my MongoDB, I have stored value as below,

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bed3f5019f0431be000412b"), 
    "reference" : "SL2PR01MB2745E4160158C08C4B7A367285C30@SL2PR01MB2745.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com,SL2PR01MB274333160158C08C4B7A367285C30@SL2PR01MB2745.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com", 
    "email_thread_id" : NumberInt(5)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bed3f5019f0431be000412b"), 
    "reference" : "SL2PR01MB2745E4160158C08C4B7A364444C30@SL2PR01MB2745.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com", 
    "email_thread_id" : NumberInt(6)
}
```

My search keyword is:

`"SL2PR01MB2745E4160158C08C4B7A364444C30@SL2PR01MB2745.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com"`

Which is match with second array from above JSON.

This is my query,

```
$referanceId= "SL2PR01MB2745E4160158C08C4B7A364444C30@SL2PR01MB2745.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com";
$mailExists = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('email_message')
            ->select('email_thread_id');            
            if ($referanceId) {
                $mailExists->whereRaw("find_in_set(".$referanceId.", reference)");
            }
$query = $mailExists->first();
```

But it gives me error like below:

> ServerException in Find.php line 299:
>       $or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easier with the laravel `where` method, this will do the comparison you want, and also make your code better readable.

You can use the following query to accomplish this:

```
DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('email_message')
    ->where("reference", $referanceId)->first();
```

If your value contains multiple reference id's as a string you can use:

```
$regexQuery = '/.*'.$referanceId.'.*/';
DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('email_message')
    ->where("reference", 'regexp', $regexQuery)->first();
```

This will match the referenceId in any position in the string.

As @hetalgotel mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316576/in-mongodb-query-with-lumen-or-and-nor-entries-need-to-be-full-objects/53317028?noredirect=1#comment93515067_53317028) another query for this is:

```
$mailExists->where("reference", 'like', "%$referanceId%")
```

This one produced the expected result in this scenario

Comment: my case is like in may database it store as 1,2,3,4,5 and I have to match "1" then I can not use this qyery

Comment: @hetalgohel, as an array or as a string containing these values?

Comment: as string , I have stored it in database

Comment: can we use find_in_set with mongodb?

Comment: @hetalgohel, I have update my answer with an extra solution for this

Comment: let me try second one

Comment: @hetalgohel, no find_in_set is not a valid mongo function, you could use the `$in` operator. But this does not work on a string, only on an array so it is not applicable in this scenario

Comment: it is not giving me error, but not gives me expected result

Comment: @hetalgohel, could you update the answer with the result you get and the expected result?

Comment: it is working with   $mailExists->where("reference", 'like', "%$referanceId%"); as expected result

Comment: @hetalgohel, ok good! I'll put that in an extra section of my answer so it is as complete as possible so it might be helpful to others :)

Comment: @hetalgohel, I also found out why the regex did not work. i forgot to put the delimiter `/` on the start and end of the query. Updated the answer with this because it should work then :) thought it might be useful to know for you